# CakePHP use Model & Controller on different Template

Tags: php, html, cakephp

I have folowed the documentation where you create the Table, Entity, Controller and then the template to display the data. On my /articles site I want to display User data now. So my User data will be on /articles and not on /users.

In /templates/Articles/index.php I can use `$articles` now, but not `$users`.
How do make use of another controller in my page?

Comment: You don't "make use of another controller". You just want to show the user name associated with each article? Use [containment](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#eager-loading-associations-via-contain) to load the related records, and then echo something like `$article->user->name` in the template.

Comment: Ok thank you. In my src/templates/Articles/index.php I inserted ``<?php echo $article->users->email ?>`` but i get the following error ``Trying to get property 'email' of non-object [ROOT\templates\Articles\index.php, line 21]``.  In my src/Model/ArticlesTable.php I have inserted ``$this->hasOne('Users'); `` in the public function initialize.  In my ArticlesController I have inserted ``$users = $this->Articles->Users->find('')->all();
        $this->set('users', $users);`` in the public function index().

Comment: What do you want to do with `$users`? Are you wanting to show a list of them somewhere? If you just want to show the name of the user for each article, then finding all users isn't useful, look at the containment link I sent instead.

Comment: I followed the tutorial where you have the basic article page. Now I want to add a custom row for the creator email. But i dont get it..

Comment: I have read through the link but I cannot see how to implement it on my index.php view..

Answer (score 0):

My goal is to add a row with the user email who published the article.

ArticlesController.php

```
public function index(){
    $articles = $this->Paginator->paginate($this->Articles->find());
    $users = $this->Articles->Users->find('')->all()->first();
    $this->set('users', $users);
    $this->set(compact('articles'));
}
```

My templates/Articles/index.php

```
    <?php foreach ($articles as $article): ?>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <?= $this->Html->link($article->title, ['action' => 'view', $article->slug]) ?>
        </td>
        <td>
          a
        </td>
        <td>
          <?php echo $article->$users ?>
        </td>
        <td>
          <?= $this->Html->link('Edit', ['action' => 'edit', $article->slug]) ?>
        </td>
        <td>
          <?= $this->Form->postLink(
                'Delete',
                ['action' => 'delete', $article->slug],
                ['confirm' => 'Are you sure?']) ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

My ArticlesTable.php

```
class ArticlesTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config): void
    {
        $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');
        $this->belongsToMany('Tags');
        $this->hasOne('Users'); 
    }
    public function beforeSave(EventInterface $event, $entity, $options)
{
    if ($entity->isNew() && !$entity->slug) {
        $sluggedTitle = Text::slug($entity->title);
        // trim slug to maximum length defined in schema
        $entity->slug = substr($sluggedTitle, 0, 191);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: `$articles = $this->Paginator->paginate($this->Articles->find()->contain('Users'));` and then get rid of anything referencing `$users`. In your template, echo something like `$article->user->name`.